# Error creating envelope through Docusign REST API - Could not cast or convert from System.String to API_REST.Models.v2.envelopeDefinition

Tags: docusignapi

I am attempting to create an envelope via the REST API and receiving an 400 response with the following error:

```
{"errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_BODY",
"message": "The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Could not cast or convert from System.String to API_REST.Models.v2.envelopeDefinition."}
```

The request is being sent to: `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<ACCOUNT_ID>/envelopes`

The body of the request is:

`{
  "templateId":"7b3b7724-3309-48bf-a8b4-65414d8686a5",
  "status":"created",
  "emailSubject":"Test subject: 2017-01-17T08:27:03.214"
}`

I am able to create this request without a problem through the REST API Explorer that has the following request body:

`{
  "emailSubject": "Test Subject",
  "status": "created",
  "templateId": "7b3b7724-3309-48bf-a8b4-65414d8686a5"
}`

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow! Please Upvote All useful answers, including those to others' questions. And please CHECK/ACCEPT the best answer for your own questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Very strange. I tried this very same body and got no problems (just changed the TemplateId, of course).

Also I tried removing some of the headers (Auth and Content-Type), but the error messages are different.

Comes to my mind:

1. Try pasting your payload in a text editor and checking if there are
   no special chars hidden;
2. I don't know which tool are you using, but
   trying this same request using curl would help you discard encoding
   issues.

Let me know if any of this helps!

Comment: Actually it turns out that I was sending the body incorrectly via our http client layer. It was being sent as a being serialized twice. Things are working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Re-posting your comment as an answer for the benefit of the community.

`Actually it turns out that I was sending the body incorrectly via our http client layer. It was being sent as a being serialized twice. Things are working as expected`